# Which are android OS is for tablets and devices?

Tags: android-versions

I am interested to know that which are android OS is for **tablets** and **devices** among below listed.

Cupcake:

```
Android 1.5
```

Donut:

```
Android 1.6
```

Eclair:

```
Android 2.0, also 2.0.1
Android 2.1
```

Froyo: (short for "frozen yogurt")

```
Android 2.2, also 2.2.x updates
```

Gingerbread:

```
Android 2.3, also 2.3.x updates
```

Honeycomb:

```
Android 3.0, also 3.0.x updates
Android 3.1
Android 3.2
```

Future Versions:

Ice Cream Sandwich:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far only Honeycomb is a tablet-only version. Other versions are used on phones, tablets and other devices (TVs, android-x86 etc.).

Answer (score 1):

While there are tablets that were able to munge other versions of Android to be used on a tablet form factor, only Honeycomb (Android 3.x) was designed specifically for tablets. (And, because of some of the kludgey wizardry they needed to do for that, they've not released the source code for Honeycomb.)

Ice Cream Sandwich merged the phone-only and tablet-only codebases.